# Is lift/drag the same as coefficient of lift/coefficient of drag?

Tags: lift, airfoil, drag

I see it being used interchangeably (for example by [Airfoil Tools Fusion360 AddIn](https://apps.autodesk.com/FUSION/en/Detail/Index?id=5447707798035545266&appLang=en&os=Win64&autostart=true)), so can I just pick an airfoil from the airfoiltools database with a certain CL/CD for my aircraft and assume L/D is the same?
An example airfoil from the database: [clarky-il](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=clarky-il)
(I know there is induced drag as well, which is not calculated in the databse)

I know the formulas, so it makes sense to me. Just want to verify there is not something I am not aware of, in case I want to calculate the lift depending on the angle of attack.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Lift and Drag are both obtained by multiplying the CL & CD by the same factors (1/2 rho V^2 S); the ratio L/D cancels out those factors, leaving CL/CD.

Comment: I thought a bit more about it and now it seems so obvious. Thanks for verifying it.